# How can I order a sections entries by their children entry postDate?

Tags: entries, ordering

Is it possible to order a section of entries by their child entries post date?

```
{% for article in craft.entries({
    section: 'articles',
    type: 'videoArticle',
    limit: 6
}).getChildren().order('postDate asc') %}
    <a href="{{ article.url }}">{{ article.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Each article has 1 child under it. I want to filter the articles by the latest postDate of the children.

Comment: Can you provide a little more information? Is this section a structure?

Comment: @LukePearce yes, i edited the description

Comment: I'm struggling to see why you have these entries set up in such a way. What are the child entries within each parent?

Comment: @LukePearce each article have multiple sub sections/children

and I want to sort the article based on the children postDate

Comment: Article1 contains (video1, video2, video3) • Article2 contains (Video1, Video2). when i loop the article.getChildren.latest() It will give me the Latest video from Article1 but I want to order the result by video postDate

Comment: Ok, but what is the content of the child entries and what is their relationship to the articles? You may be able to set up your site structure differently to achieve what you want.

Comment: For article It's just a short description of the topic and they have multiple sub section/children. I want to sort the article based on the children postDate. If I add new children for article2, article2 will be sorted first

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40164/discussion-between-luke-pearce-and-densityx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want.

```
{% set videos = craft.entries({
    section: 'articles',
    type: 'video',
    level: 2,
}) %}

{% set articleIds = [] %}
{% for video in videos %}
    {% set article = video.getParent() %}
    {% set articleIds = articleIds|merge([article.id]) %}
{% endfor %}

{% set articles = craft.entries({
    id: articleIds,
    fixedOrder: true,
    limit: 6
}) %}
```

You go through all the videos and collect the IDs of the parent article entries. Once you have the IDs, make sure to set [`fixedOrder`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#fixedOrder) in the final criteria model and the entries are retuned in the same order as the IDs in the `id` param.

Note that the [`getParent`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#getParent) function queries the database for each video in your section. You might want to consider caching that piece of code.

And you can also test if replacing the code in the for loop with the following performs better.

```
{% set articleId = video.getAncestors(1).ids()[0] %}
{% set articleIds = articleIds|merge([articleId]) %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Works great, I don't know that we can use fixedOrder to do that

and using the "id" to get the entries is really something, can't think up of this method at first.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this correctly, you need two loops: one to loop over the parent entries in the section and then a second to get the parent's children. That'll give you the control you need.

Something like (untested):

```
{% for parentArticle in craft.entries({ 
           section: 'articles', type: 'videoArticle', limit: 6
        }).order('postDate asc') 
 %}

 {# do what you want with the parent, just a heading and description here #}

 <h2>{{parentArticle.title}}</h2>
  {{parentArticle.topLevelDescription}}

 {# loop over the children underneath the parent sorted by most recent #}

  <ul>
  {% for childArticle in parentArticle.children.order('postDate asc') %}
      <li><a href="{{childArticle.url}}">{{childArticle.title}}</a>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>

{% endfor %}
```